Python Polars SQL Interface results in InvalidOperationError on multiple joins
I am struggling to run a query that joins 3 tables together with the middle table joining the other two.

Table A has a column "a".
Table B has columns "a" and "b".
Table C has columns "b" and "c". (Only column "b" is required).

MWE:
import polars as pl
ctx = pl.SQLContext({"dual": pl.DataFrame({"dummy": ["X"]})})
sql = """
select *
from (select 123 a from dual) tbl_a
inner join (select 123 a, 'value' b from dual) tbl_b
on tbl_a.a = tbl_b.a
inner join (select 'value' b, 'value2' c from dual) tbl_c
on tbl_c.b = tbl_b.b
--using (b)
"""
print(ctx.execute(sql, eager=True))

The above produces the following error:
InvalidOperationError: collect_compound_identifiers: left_name="tbl_a", right_name="tbl_c", tbl_a="tbl_c", tbl_b="tbl_b".
One workaround that I found was to replace the on tbl_c.b = tbl_b.b clause with using (b), as the commented out SQL above shows. Another workaround is to reorder the joins so that tbl_b is selected from first followed by tbl_c and then tbl_a. However, these are not ideal solutions.
How do I get around this? Thanks.

Your code runs without error on the latest pre-release. v1.0.0-beta.1

Thanks @jqurious, seems to be working on 0.20.31 as well. I had 0.20.19 when I ran it a few minutes ago I believe. Will close the issue.

If you encounter SQL errors it's probably better to go directly to Github as it is under active development. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3AA-sql

Yup; this one was fixed by https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/16507 (along with a host of other join-related updates/fixes). GitHub Issues are definitely the best way to bring a Polars SQL bug to my attention ;)
